# how to make a calculate column in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

how to make a calculate(4 digits if prefix not start with 0).  column type using powerapps in dataverse

example :
0011,0100 like this

if I enter the 456 then I want to store 0456 in dataverse

see the below image paperno column :

[paperno column image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F2oR.png)

[paperno column image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liUOI.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
Text(Value(yourNumberValueHere), "0000")
```

[image]

Comment: it gives an error when I write this ```default = Text(Value(DataCardValue3.Text),"0000")```  error is this rule creates a circular referance between properties, which is not allowed

Comment: see this for more clarification https://imgur.com/kEz6B1W

Comment: My solution will go wherever you are submitting your data to. Are you looking for a user to enter data into a field, then click outside of the field (or tab away), and have it auto-format to have the leading zeros?

Comment: Are you looking for a user to enter data into a field, then click outside of the field (or tab away), and have it auto-format to have the leading zeros? ----- yes exactly I want